# asp.net core + angular2 JWT bearer

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, authorization, jwt, bearer-token

I am looking for how to implemented authorization with JWT bearer in asp.net-core 1.0 with angular2.
I ask you guys for sample or something like that?

Comment: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples has samples of using OpenIddict. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4 has them for IdentityServer4. Once you have a sense of the territory, please return to ask an answerable question.

Comment: mhmm, I want something simpler as cookie authorization in aps.net MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net core 1.1 has lib. can do JWT bearer easily, please check here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-achieve-a-bearer-9448db57

And for angular as client, see this:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-authorization-914d126b

As MS$ provides middleware UseJwtBearerAuthentication, jwt bearer token will be simply use it at backend; for frontend save the token in sessionStorage after login, when talking to backend, set header of http request as:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem(this.tokenKey););
```

See [here](https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETcoreAngularJWT) for full details